# Syntax error: Missing operand after 'ID' operator

Tags: vb.net

i know theres loads of posts with this problem, but i cant seem to find the error in my code, any ideas?

heres my code:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    On Error GoTo SearchErr

    If txtSearch.Text = "" Then
        Exit Sub

    Else
        Dim cantFind As String = txtSearch.Text

        MainBindingSource.Filter = "(Convert(ID, 'System.String') LIKE '" & txtSearch.Text & "')" & _
            "OR (Student ID LIKE '" & txtSearch.Text & "') OR (First Name LIKE '" & txtSearch.Text & "')" & _
            "OR (Last Name LIKE '" & txtSearch.Text & "')"

        If MainBindingSource.Count <> 0 Then
            With dgvStudentInfo
                .DataSource = MainBindingSource

            End With
```

Im trying to search an Access DB in Vb.net

Comment: Too much repetition in your string concat, learn to use `String.Format` then you can debug it better. `String.Format("(Convert(ID, 'System.String') LIKE '{0}')OR (Student ID LIKE '{0}') OR (First Name LIKE '{0}')OR (Last Name LIKE '{0}')", txtSearch.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

I think SQL is seeing "Student ID" as two words. If your table fields really have spaces in them you need to add brackets, "[Student ID]". (You may need single or double quote identifiers instead of brackets. Not sure.)